# SPI NOR Flash: Unstable reads

Tags: pi-3, gpio, spi

So I hooked up an Winbond `25Q256JVEQ` to my Raspi3 via SPI (spi0.0) and want to read its content.
I use the `jedec-nor-spi` dtoverlay so its available as MTD.

However when I want to read the chips memory with e.g. `sudo hexdump -C /dev/mtd0` I receive very unexpected and different results:

For every read I do, the first bytes are always `0x00`. I know the content of the chip and `02 00 10 00` should be at the very beginning.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo hexdump -C /dev/mtd0
00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00005000  02 00 10 00 00 00 00 f8  02 00 10 00 00 00 00 f6  |................|
00005010  02 00 10 00 00 00 00 f4  02 00 10 00 00 00 00 f2  |................|
```

When I do the exact same read operation again, the data starts at a different offset:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo hexdump -C /dev/mtd0
00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00003000  03 00 10 00 00 00 00 00  03 00 10 00 00 00 00 fe  |................|
00003010  02 00 10 00 00 00 00 fc  02 00 10 00 00 00 00 fa  |................|
```

and again, another time:

```
sudo hexdump -C /dev/mtd0
00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00006000  03 00 10 00 00 00 00 00  03 00 10 00 00 00 00 fe  |................|
00006010  02 00 10 00 00 00 00 fc  02 00 10 00 00 00 00 fa  |................|
```

I observed this `offset` to fluctuate around `0x2000` and `0x6000`.
I already tried another `25Q256JVEQ` but the behavior is the same.

Am I missing something? The chip supports a clock of up to 133MHz while the Raspi-Overlay is far below that. I also can't write to it or erase it using my Pi.

Comment: To write or erase, there should be /dev/mtdblockX. There are also tools specially made for mtd device (mtdwrite or mtd_write). The offset is odd and possibly suggests some timing issue.